# When adding target to button, why must target action be an objc func?

Tags: ios, swift

Why does a button action need to be a function declared with objc? Im curious as to what the difference is between an objc func and a func and why a button can't simply reference it's action to a func.

Edit: I am using Swift. Thank you very much for your time.

```
var thisButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(thisFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func thisFunction() {
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: UIKit could have been implemented to work with closures (which would also enable the use of Swift functions and methods, which are themselves closures), but that wouldn't support Interface Builder. IB needs to store a `@IBAction`'s name, bake it into the nib/xib file, and use that at runtime to retrieve the correct function to call. Swift doesn't have (yet) have an (exposed) reflection mechanism that would support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Swift generates code that is only available to other Swift code, but
>   if you need to interact with the Objective-C runtime – all of UIKit,
>   for example – you need to tell Swift what to do.
>
> That’s where the @objc attribute comes in: when you apply it to a
>   class or method it instructs Swift to make those things available to
>   Objective-C as well as Swift code. So, any time you want to call a
>   method from a UIBarButtonItem or a Timer, you’ll need to mark that
>   method using @objc so it’s exposed – both of those, and many others,
>   are Objective-C code.

Refer :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html